# getActivityInfo method doesn't work for disabled component

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I am working with one activity and certain logic requires enabling and disabling this activity from time to time. Also, I used package manager API to check if I have this activity in system at all. This is getActivityInfo method.

And for some reason I catch NameNotFoundException after calling this method if the activity is disabled at that moment. It is kinda strange. Is it a feature or am I doing something wrong? I do know that I haven't misspelled the package and activity names, they are valid.

I cannot use MATCH_DISABLED_COMPONENTS flag sinse it's entered only on 24 level API which is forbidden for me.
[image]

Comment: Okay, how about you programmatically enable the Activity just for inquiry and then disable it a moment later?

Comment: Yes, but the whole point of using activityInfo was to determine whether this activity is enabled or not. :)

Comment: I agree but there is no support library for PackageManager so this is a hack around it. Also, the original thinking of Android designer must have been, "Whatever is enable is effectively VALID". So, the class ActivityInfo has grown with requirements but you have to make do for newer features for your case.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** 
For the API level 24 problem, I can suggest programmatically enabling the Activity for a moment and then making the inquiry and then disabling it with,

```
setComponentEnabledSetting(ComponentName componentName, int newState, int flags)
```

where the state is:

> The new enabled state for the component. The legal values for this
>   state are: COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
>   COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED and COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT
>   The last one removes the setting, thereby restoring the component's
>   state to whatever was set in it's manifest (or enabled, by default).

---

There are flags provided in the docs for this method and one of the flags is `MATCH_DISABLED_COMPONENTS`. This implies that without this flag, it doesn't check any disabled component and you must enable it for your case.

So call it like,

```
getActivityInfo(componentName, MATCH_DISABLED_COMPONENTS);
```

You should then not get this exception.

Comment: yes, the description sounds reasonable. But the problem that I cannot use 24 level API. And one more thing: method getApplicationInfo works valid with disabled packages (without any flags). Maybe it is not the same, but still it is strange to me.